# OperationContext.Current is null and all other contexts too

Tags: wcf, httpcontext

I have a WCF service defined as following:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public partial class FrontEndService : IFrontEndService
```

However, most of the time (but not always) `InstanceContext.Current` is null, as well as `HttpContext.Current` and `OperationContext.Current` is also null.

What am I missing? What I want to do is store some data in `HttpContext.Current.Items` or a similar collection that exists for the length of the request.

Comment: Unclear if this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service was just being called from another thread, and not via HTTP, that's why all Contexts were null.

Comment: Hi Egor, what do you mean by `from another thread`? If I call wcf from MVC controller's action does it counts as another thread and what can I do to obtain operationcontext?